# mod rewrite, how to get "global" css?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dff/300Hemsidor/testas/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ((js|css|images)\/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ((functions|css|images)\/.*)$ /$1 [L,NC] 


# FORUM
RewriteRule ^forum$ index2.php?site=forum [L]
RewriteRule ^forum/cat/([0-9]+)/([A-za-z0-9\-]+)$ index2.php?site=forum&cat=$1 [L]
```

When i visit:
http://localhost/dff/300hemsidor/testas/forum - It works with css and everything
When i visit http://localhost/dff/300hemsidor/testas/forum/cat/62/this-is-a-category - The css and everything is in a different dir and doesn't get included.

My question is, how do i make the css/js/img files to get "absolute" ?

Comment: You link them with `/path/to/file.css` not `path/to/file.css`.

Comment: Prepend your URLs with a slash or use a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag.

Comment: It amazes me how often this comes up.

Comment: @PanamaJack It does? I googled it and i searched here but i didnt find a good answer. But then im so sorry.